# Liars, adjunctions, and functions $f : S \rightarrow UFS$. Does this lead anywhere interesting?

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, category-theory, universal-algebra, monads

A student of mine was recently given the following question:

> - "At least one of us is lying," said Andrew.
> - "Only one of us is lying," said Bertas.
> - "Squeak, two of us are lying," said the Chipmunk.
> - "Either three or four of us are lying," said Daisy.
> - "Elmo thinks that everybody is lying," said Elmo.
>
> How many liars are there altogether?

We can rehash this into language that is more easy to analyse as follows:

> - Andrew: the number of truthspeakers is an element of $\{0,1,2,3,4\}.$
> - Bertas: the number of truthspeakers is an element of $\{4\}.$
> - Chipmunk: the number of truthspeakers is an element of $\{3\}.$
> - Daisy: the number of truthspeakers is an element of $\{1,2\}.$
> - Elmo: the number of truthspeakers is an element of $\{0\}.$

With a bit of thought, we see that the answer is "$2$ truthspeakers."

- It can't be $0$, because then Andrew and Elmo would be truthspeakers.
- It can't be $1$, because then both Andrew and Daisy would be truthspeakers.
- It **can** be $2$, with Andrew and Daisy being the only truthspeakers.
- It can't be $3$ or more, because the intersection of any three distinct sets listed above is empty.

Anyway, I thought this question was pretty cool, enough so that I tried throwing some abstract nonsense at it. Here's what I came up with.

> **Definition 0.**
>   Consider a category concrete over $\mathbf{Set}.$ Lets refer to its objects as *algebras*, and lets assume there's a free algebra on every set. Write $U$ for the underlying set functor, $F$ for the free functor, and $\Phi$ for the adjunction $F \dashv U$.
>
> Given
>
> - a set $S$ equipped with a function $f : S \rightarrow UFS$
> - an algebra $X$,
>
> a *realization* of $f$ in $X$ is a function $g : S \rightarrow UX$ such that $g=U(\Phi_{S,X}(g)) \circ f$

For instance:

- Work over the concrete category of Boolean algebras; so in particular, $F$ is the free Boolean algebra functor.
- Define $S = \{A,B,C,D,E\}$.
- Define $f : S \rightarrow UFS$ so that it expresses whom the truthspeakers are conjectured to be:

For example: $$f(A) = \neg(\neg A \wedge \neg B \wedge \neg C \wedge \neg D \wedge \neg E), \qquad f(E) = \bot$$

Then the unique realization of $f$ in the boolean algebra $\{0,1\}$ is $$g : A,D \mapsto 1, \qquad g : B,C,E \mapsto 0.$$

Here's a more simple example:

> **Liar's paradox.** The function $f : \{x\} \rightarrow F(\{x\})$ given by $x \mapsto \neg x$ has no realizations in $\{0,1\}$.

What I'd like to know is:

> **Question.** Does this train of thought lead to any interesting mathematics?

Comment: As the conductor of this train of thought, you may have to explicitly show us a few more stops along the way. Better yet, as I use trains to seek treasure, draw me a treasure map of where your train has gone so far...

Comment: @RicardoJRademacher, I like the way you construct your sentences. One thought I've had is that if $F$ is the free $R$-module functor, then functions $S \rightarrow UFS$ are the same as morphisms $FS \rightarrow FS$, which are basically square matrices. So it seems that we can speak of "the realizations of the square matrix $T$ in the $R$-module $X$." I haven't quite got my head around what this means yet...

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have too much more to say, except that maybe these realization thingy's show up naturally in other branches of abstract algebra, like group theory, ring theory, etc. and maybe they matter.

Comment: "I haven't quite got my head around what this means yet." Because you are thinking too much like a mathematician and too little like an artist.  Category Theory requires an appreciation of "Aesthetics"... knowing what a "good looking" diagram looks like or "well behaived" morphisms.  Long story short, IF YOU CAN DRAW IT YOU CAN UNDERSTAND IT. Stop trying to find a mathematical equation to say what you want to say, start drawing what you want to say and then let "categorical aesthetics" of universality and naturalness take over.

Comment: "One thought I've had is that if FF is the free RR-module functor," What does this look like to you?

Comment: "hen functions S→UFSS→UFS are the same as morphisms FS→FSFS→FS, which are basically square matrices." Based on your answer to the above, what does this look like to you? In pictures with lines and boxes, not in mathematical jargon.

Comment: and so on and so on, building bigger more beautiful pictures from categorical "widgets"

Comment: @goblin when you write $\Phi_{S,X}(g)$, do you mean the adjoint morphism $FS\xrightarrow{g'} X$ for which $S\xrightarrow{g} UX$ factors as $S\to UFS\xrightarrow{Ug'}UX$? If so, then the condition $S\xrightarrow{g}UX$ being a realization of $f$ is equivalent to the condition that $g'\circ f'=g'$. Then what you're doing is considering (generalized) fixed points of endomorphisms in the opposite category of the category of algebras...

Comment: How does Andrew know what the rest of them are going to say?

Answer (score 0):

> Question. Does this train of thought lead to any interesting mathematics?

I don't know the answer to this, but I can see something interesting you can do already:

> Work over the concrete category of Boolean algebras; so in particular, FF is the free Boolean algebra functor.

How would your results change if you changed the underlying logic, from Boolean to Heyting for example (so that there is no law of excluded middle)? That could be interesting, even if just to compare with the example(s) you've already worked out.

Comment: I think we'd have to replace the Boolean algebra $\{0,1\}$ with something more complicated to get anything interesting in this way.